# jquery register multiple keypress events on page

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

I  have a form that I am using 'next' and 'previous' buttons to navigate through by showing or hiding each subsequent field.

```
<ol class="fs-fields">
                <ul>
                    <label>{{form.project_name.label_tag}}</label>
                    <input id="id_project_name" name="project_name" type="text" placeholder="Project Name" required/>
                    <button type="button" class="fs-next">Next</button>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <label>{{form.project_orgName.label_tag}}</label>
                    <input id="id_project_orgName" name="project_orgName" type="text" required>
                    <button type="button" class="fs-next">Next</button>
                    <button type="button" class="fs-previous">Back</button>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <label>{{form.project_orgWebsite.label_tag}}</label>
                    <input id="id_project_orgWebsite" name="project_orgWebsite" type="text" required>
                    <button type="button" class="fs-previous">Back</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="">Submit for Review</button>
                </ul>
            </ol>
```

I would like to run this function each time the next button is pressed or enter is pressed while the input form is selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input').focus();
clickNext();
clickPrevious();
nextOnEnter();
i = 1;

})


function clickNext() {
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".fs-next").click(function() {        
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    // //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    // $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");


    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show(); 
            $('input').focus();
            $('.dot' + i.toString()).addClass('completed')
            $('.dot' + i.toString()).removeClass('current')
            i = i+1;
            $('.dot' + i.toString()).addClass('current')
        }, 
    });
});
}

function nextOnEnter() {
$('input').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
        $('.fs-next').click();//Trigger search button click event
    }
});
}
```

This function works great the first time but it works only once:

Could someone help me understand to have the nextOnEnter() function work more than one time?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?  There could be an issue because you have multiple .fs-next buttons on the page.  Do you have a working/semi-working demo?  I also don't see where nextOnEnter is being called.

Comment: I edited the jquery above to include the code for where nextOnEnter is called. There are no errors in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Will you console.log(animating) at the end of your complete code? I'm curious if it reached the end of animate complete

Comment: It's always clicking the 1st fs-next button.  It you actually click the next button.  This is bound to that specific button.  On enter, It's always clicking the 1st button.  You are just making the 1st button transparent, but it still exists in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will fix some parts of your code, since, for example, when you are doing `$('input').focus();` you are triggering the focus event on all the inputs tags of your html code, and i don't think you want this.

```
// Variables with global scope.

var i;
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; // Fieldsets.
var left, opacity, scale;             // Fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating;                        // Flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(document).ready(function()
{
    i = 1;

    // Trigger the focus event only in the first input element.

    $('input#id_project_name').focus();

    // Register events listeners.

    clickNext();
    clickPrevious();
    nextOnEnter();
});

// Register a listener for click event on all elements with class ".fs-next".

function clickNext()
{
    $(".fs-next").click(function()
    {
        if (animating)
            return false;

        animating = true;
        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

        // Hide the current fieldset with animation style.

        current_fs.animate(
            {opacity: 0},
            {
                step: function(now, mx) {

                    // As the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0, stored in "now"
                    // 1. Scale current_fs down to 80%.
                    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;

                    // 2. Bring next_fs from the right(50%).
                    left = (now * 50) + "%";

                    // 3. Increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in.
                    opacity = 1 - now;

                    current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
                    next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
                },
                duration: 800, 
                complete: function() {

                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;

                    // Show the next fieldset.
                    next_fs.show();

                    // Set focus on next input.
                    next_fs.find("input").focus();

                    // Setup classes.
                    $('.dot' + i.toString()).addClass('completed').removeClass('current');
                    i = i + 1;
                    $('.dot' + i.toString()).addClass('current')
                }
            }
        );
    });
}

// Register a trigger of click event on all inputs when "enter key" is pressed.

function nextOnEnter()
{
    $('input').keypress(function(e)
    {
        if (e.which == 13)
            $(this).parent().find('.fs-next').click();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense and worked perfectly. Appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome! I will try to give a better format to the code just in case this can help to others peoples

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your Enter keypress:

```
function nextOnEnter() {
$('input').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){//Enter key pressed
     $(this).parent().find('.fs-next').click();
    }
});
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3yvur0jh/1/